# AWK to Python For Mbox

Tags: python, awk, mbox

What would be the best Pythonic way of implementing this awk command in python?

```
awk 'BEGIN{chunk=0} /^From /{msgs++;if(msgs==500){msgs=0;chunk++}}{print > "chunk_" chunk ".txt"}' mbox
```

I'm using this now to split up enormous mailbox (mbox format) files.

I'm trying a recursive method right now.

```
def chunkUp(mbox, chunk=0):
    with open(mbox, 'r') as bigfile:
        msg = 0
        for line in bigfile:
            if msg == 0: 
                with open("./TestChunks/chunks/chunk_"+str(chunk)+".txt", "a+") as cf:
                    if line.startswith("From "): msg += 1
                    cf.write(line)
                    if msg > 20: chunkUp(mbox, chunk+1)
```

I would love to be able to implement this in python and be able to resume progress if it is interrupted. Working on that bit now.

I'm tying my brain into knots! Cheers!

Comment: recursive is bad, because the files aren't closed (too many open files after a while)

Comment: good point, I'll move away from that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your recursive approach is doomed to fail: you may end up having too many open files at once, since the `with` blocks don't exit until the end of the program.

Better have one handle open and write to it, close & reopen new handle when "From" is encountered.

also open your files in write mode, not append. The code below tries to do the minimal operations & tests to write each line in a file, and close/open another file when `From:` is found. Also, in the end, the last file is closed.

```
def chunkUp(mbox):
    with open(mbox, 'r') as bigfile:
        handle = None
        chunk = 0

        for line in bigfile:
            if line.startswith("From "):
                 # next (or first) file
                 chunk += 1
                 if handle is not None:
                    handle.close()
                 handle = None

            # file was closed / first file: create a new one
            if handle is None:
               handle = open("./TestChunks/chunks/chunk_{}.txt".format(chunk), "w")
            # write the line in the current file
            handle.write(line)

         if handle is not None:
             handle.close()
```

I haven't tested it, but it's simple enough, it should work. If file doesn't have "From" in the first line, all lines before are stored in `chunk_0.txt` file.

Comment: I was stuck on trying to use with open(). This is a wonderful solution. I'll implement the 500 msg per chunk as the awk command specifies with this. I'm marking as answered since it grappled with the mental block of handling open files. Thank you!